# Is it possible to disable auto formatting only for Html pages (not c#) on VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

During the design html pages or aspx pages, I like to do the pure coding without Html Designer. The problem is that I like to have the following format on html page for better readability.

```
<div>
  <% if (1 == 1) { %>
    Hello
  <% } else { %>
    World
  <% } %>
</div>
```

As you can guess, whenever you type '}' or ';' or etc, visual studio try to do the auto format and change to the following format

```
<div>
  <% if (1 == 1) 
     { %>
    Hello
  <% }
     else
     { %>
    World
  <% } %>
</div>
```

The question is "Is it possible to disable auto formatting just only for HTML pages on VS2010? (NOT for C# code, I still like to have auto formatting for C# pages)"

Comment: I can't stand this either and have been searching for an answer! Extremely annoying and steals a decent amount of productivity..

Comment: Microsoft have a new ViewEngine in MVC 3.0 called "Razor" which is really good for developing website and there is no annoying auto format like Webform ViewEngine

Comment: @ensecoz Unfortunately, the annoyance (*I'm sure we've all experienced*) has carried over with Razor; it's rather terrible at times.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, go to these two spots:

> `Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Tabs > Indenting`

Select the *None* radio button.

> `Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Tabs > Miscellaneous`

Uncheck *Format HTML on paste*.

Comment: thanks, sound good. I will try it and if it works I'll come and mark your answer

Comment: nope, this is not working. when select "None" for Indenting, it means that whenever you enter the newline, you won't get any indenting for that. but when you type <% } %>, it still do auto format.

Answer (score 5):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > Jscript > Formatting

Uncheck "Format completed line on Enter" and "Format completed block on }"

Comment: The question is about C#, not javascript.

Comment: I actually was looking for the solution with JS so this solution helped me! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, and I found out that it was due to Resharper, not Visual Studio.

To disable html formatting in Resharper, go to:

`RESHARPER > Options > Code Editing > HTML > Editor`

and uncheck "Auto-format on enter" and "Auto-format on closing tag"

Answer (score 0):

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Formatting > Tag Specific Options...

It's a confusing dialog, but notice the "preview" pane near the bottom to see how each rule is going to be applied.